# Getting W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for XXX found on class

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am getting this error for every child under the parent node (GID) for Games in my Firebase json tree.

So that error message is for AwayTeam, HomeTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore, etc...Its like it did NOT map anything properly!?

The firebase structure is like the following:

```
Games
    --- GID
        ----- AwayTeam
        ----- HomeTeam
        ----- AwayScore
        ----- HomeScore
              etc...
```

My Adapter file is like the following:

```
public class PoolAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoolAdapter.PoolViewHolder> {

    public PoolAdapter(Dashboard dashboardFragment, String userID) {

        this.mDashboardFragment = dashboardFragment;

        mPoolRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        playerInPoolRef = mPoolRef.child("PlayerInPool").child(userID).orderByValue().equalTo(true);

        playerInPoolRef.addValueEventListener(new PlayersInPoolChildEventListener());

    }

    private class PlayersInPoolChildEventListener implements ValueEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                getPoolData(dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}

    }


    private void getPoolData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String poolID = snapshot.getKey();

            poolRef = mPoolRef.child("Pools").child(poolID);

            poolRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    getGameData(dataSnapshot);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}

            });

        }

    }

    private void getGameData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String gameID = dataSnapshot.child("GameId").getValue().toString();

        gameRef = mPoolRef.child("Games").child(gameID);

        gameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                loadPlayerDashboard(dataSnapshot);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}

        });

    }

    private void loadPlayerDashboard(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Log.d(TAG, "*** Database snapshot: " + dataSnapshot); <-- Displays the correct Firebase information

        Pools pool = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pools.class);

        mPools.add(pool);
        Collections.sort(mPools);

    }

}
```

My Model class object is as follows:

```
public class Pools implements Comparable<Pools> {

    private String _poolID;
    //
    private String _poolName;
    private String _poolPassword;

    private String _gameID;
    private String _awayTeam;
    private String _homeTeam;

    private String _gameTime;
    private String _gameDate;

    public Pools() { }

    public Pools(String poolID, String poolName, String gameID, String awayTeamName, String homeTeamName, String gameDate, String gameTime) {

        this._poolID = poolID;
        this._poolName = poolName;
        //
        this._gameID = gameID;
        this._awayTeam = awayTeamName;
        this._homeTeam = homeTeamName;

        this._gameDate = gameDate;
        this._gameTime = gameTime;

    }

    public String get_poolID() {
        return _poolID;
    }

    public void set_poolID(String _poolID) {
        this._poolID = _poolID;
    }

    public String get_poolName() {
        return _poolName;
    }

    public void set_poolName(String _poolName) {
        this._poolName = _poolName;
    }

    public String get_poolPassword() {
        return _poolPassword;
    }

    public void set_poolPassword(String _poolPassword) {
        this._poolPassword = _poolPassword;
    }

    public String get_gameID() {
        return _gameID;
    }

    public void set_gameID(String _gameID) {
        this._gameID = _gameID;
    }

    public String get_awayTeam() {
        return _awayTeam;
    }

    public void set_awayTeam(String _awayTeam) {
        this._awayTeam = _awayTeam;
    }

    public String get_homeTeam() {
        return _homeTeam;
    }

    public void set_homeTeam(String _homeTeam) {
        this._homeTeam = _homeTeam;
    }

    public String get_gameTime() {
        return _gameTime;
    }

    public void set_gameTime(String _gameTime) {
        this._gameTime = _gameTime;
    }

    public String get_gameDate() {
        return _gameDate;
    }

    public void set_gameDate(String _gameDate) {
        this._gameDate = _gameDate;
    }

}
```

which has all the getters and setters so I am not sure why I am getting the error!?

I know the data is there as log log statement that you see above in my Adapter displays the following:
`*** Database snapshot: DataSnapshot { key = 2019020300, value = {HomeTeam=Los Angeles Rams, GSIS=57833, GameYear=2019, isPlayed=true, hBackground=hTeam/rams.png, HomeId=29, hScore=0, GameTime=6:30, AwayId=31, aBackground=aTeam/patriots.png, SportID=1, aScore=0, Qtr=Pregame, WeekId=22, GameDate=20190203, AwayTeam=New England Patriots, SeasonType=SB} }`

Does anyone know how I can resolve this!?

Comment: if you have set minifyenabled to true in build.gradle then mostly this is your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58879798/8899344

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over dataSnapshot.getChildren(

```
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Pools pool = childSnapshot.getValue(Pools.class);
             }
```